# Database restriction by the value of a field

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship

I am making a database to storage "Users" and "Companies", and another table "User Role" for the relationship between users and companies (clients, workers and manager).

My problem is that I want to restrict to a unique registry of "User Role" when the role is manager, because I don't want any user to have more than one company.

I think there must be an easy solution, but I'm totally blocked by now.

I would appreciate any advice or guideline.

Answer (score 0):

if you only want one user to be a manager at one company, then you might create a UNIQUE INDEX on the values for User_id and the field that holds the manager indicator

Comment: If I understood correctly, you propose me to have in the "User Role" table a field (maybe a TINY_INT) to say if this role is manager or not, is that correct? It seems a good solution but I think it could be repetitive if I have another field which say if the user is Client, Worker or Manager.

Comment: or use the other field... is it possible that the same user can be a client and a manager at the same company at the same time?

Comment: No, but a user can be manager of a company, and client of other different companies.